# python3 locking / deadlock

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, locking, deadlock

How can I verify if a lock is actually being enforced? I've written the following code that will either get or define a color in a color dictionary. I've included threading and locking but I'm not sure that the locking portion is actually doing anything. Is locking implemented correctly?

```
lock_all = Lock()

def start_server (hostname, port, colord):
    """Start the server and serve clients"""
    sock = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Created server socket")
    sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    print("Bound socket to %s port %d" % (host, port))
    sock.listen(1)
    print("The socket is listening for connections")
    print("Press control-C to interrupt")
    try:
        while True:
             conn, addr = sock.accept()
             print("Got a connection from %s, %d" % addr)
             t = Thread(target=serve, args=(conn, colord))
             t.start()
             conn.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
         print("\nServer shutting down in response to keyboard interrupt.")
         sock.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
         sock.close()
         print("Closed socket")
         raise e
    except Exception as e:
         sock.close()
         raise e 

def serve (conn, colord):

    # Make file-like objects ins, outs
    ins = conn.makefile('r', 512)
    outs = conn.makefile('w', 512)


    try:
        for request in ins:
            req = json.loads(request)
            response = handle_request(req, colord)
            outs.write(json.dumps(response))
            outs.write('\r\n')
            outs.flush()

        print("Client disconnected")
    except Exception as e:
         print("ERROR: ", e)
         print("Closing connection")
    finally:
         ins.close()
         outs.close()

def handle_request(req, colord):

    try:
         cmd = req['request-type']
         print('handle_request; cmd =', repr(cmd))
         if cmd == 'get':
             name = req['name']
             return handle_get(name, colord)
         elif cmd == 'def':
             name = req['name']
             r = req['r']
             g = req['g']
             b = req['b']
             return handle_def(name, r, g, b, colord)
         else:
             return error_invalid()
    except Exception as e:
         print("ERROR:", e)
         return error_invalid()

 def handle_get(name, colord):
     #BEGIN CRITICAL SECTION
     lock_all.acquire()
     try:
         if name in colord:
              return value(colord[name])

         else:
              return error_unknown_color()
     finally:
         lock_all.release()
     #END CRITICAL SECTION

def handle_def(name, r, g, b, colord):
     #BEGIN CRITICAL SECTION
     lock_all.acquire()
     try:
          colord[name] = (r, g, b)
          return ok()

     except:
          return error_invalid()
     finally:
          lock_all.release()
     #END CRITICAL SECTION
```

Comment: Please fix the indenting of your code.  What you have posted currently is not valid.

Comment: Sorry about that fixed the indenting, not sure where it got messed up.